# C++ Template Template Type Inference

Tags: c++, templates, inference

So i have a struct something like this:

```
template<uint8 N>
class SomeStruct { ... };

class Node {
    SomeStruct<0> a;
    SomeStruct<2> b;
    SomeStruct<4> c;
};
```

and I have a template function, that does something **on a specific field of Node**:

```
template<uint8 N>
using NodeFieldPtr = SomeStruct<N> Node::*;

template <uint8 N, NodeFieldPtr<N> F>
void doSomething(Node* node0, Node* node1) { ... }
```

I find it annoying to have to **specify "N" on `doSomething()` again**, because calling it is not elegant:

```
doSomething<2, &Node::b>(...);
```

How can I tell the compiler "nicely" not to care about the exact template arguments of `SomeStruct<>`. Something like a **wildcard**.

```
template <NodeFieldPtr<?> F> //<- unfortunately not C++
void doSomething(Node* node0, Node* node1) { ... }

doSomething<&Node::b>(...);
```

Comment: Most painless suggestion so far: "C++17 template <auto F>". But does not describe the signature of the function very well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `auto` non-type template parameter since C++17:

```
template <auto F>
void doSomething() { }

int main()
{
    doSomething<&Node::b>();
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jaz7ooTx6)

Comment: yeeas... but not "constrainy" enough

Answer (score 3):

How about `auto` (since C++17):

```
template <auto F>
void doSomething(Node* node0, Node* node1)
{
// ... 
}
```

Comment: yeeas... but not "constrainy" enough

Comment: You might create a concept in C++20, or use SFINAE/static_assert with appropriate traits in C++17.

Comment: @StefTheDrummer it is constrained by the mere fact that you use the pointer to call a member of `Node` somewhere in the implementation. You can improve it by providing nicer error messages, but the constraint is already there (if not, why artificially introducing it?)

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answers, if you wish to constrain the type of `F` *and* have the syntax you are after, you may employ a custom type trait:

```
template<int N>
using NodeFieldPtr = SomeStruct<N> Node::*;

template<typename> struct is_some_struct_memptr                  : std::false_type{};
template<int N>    struct is_some_struct_memptr<NodeFieldPtr<N>> : std::true_type {};
```

With that in hand, we can constrain `doSomething` in C++17:

```
template <auto F>
auto doSomething(Node*, Node*) -> std::enable_if_t<is_some_struct_memptr<decltype(F)>::value>
{
}
```

Or even C++20:

```
template <auto F>
void doSomething(Node*, Node*) requires (is_some_struct_memptr<decltype(F)>::value)
{
}
```

Comment: matter of style, but I don't like your naming. `is_some_struct_memptr` seems to imply that it checks for being memptr to "some" struct (read as "any struct"), but it is only about `SomeStruct`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - If one entirely ignores the fact I used the OP's own name, sure.

Comment: i am not ignoring that, to the contrary, thats just my point. OPs struct is called `SomeStruct` not `some_struct`. Nevermind, its clear what is meant from context

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - It is certainly called `some_struct` when converted to snake case. Talk about wasting keystrokes on a non-issue.

Comment: o-boy-o-boy. we are entering the realm of c++ template metaprogramming.  Event though this way a call to doSomething() gets very restrictive - it definitly doesnt get more descriptive or readable...

Comment: @StefTheDrummer - Spend about a decade meta-programming. It will become readable enough. You can't have your cake and eat it too. You want a constrained parameter with nice syntax? The constraint has to be spelled out and applied by *you*.

Comment: @rustyx - Affecting the overload set and thus the behavior of the program? Sound like meta-programming. And it employs templates, so...